# My class diagram needs to model a relationship with varying quantities

Tags: uml, class-design, class-diagram, engineering

I am trying to design a restaurant ordering system in UML, which should also include the stock system.

One of the classes is a `Dish` (i.e. a dish on the menu), and another is an `Ingredient`.

My initial idea was to place an aggregation of `Ingredient`s within `Dish`, but I've also read that a many to many relationship is more appropriate.

My problem is that in this case, simply having a relationship isn't enough. For instance a `Dish` could have 30g of `Ingredient` A, while another `Dish` could have 20g of `Ingredient` A.

How can I model this kind of dependency in UML?

Comment: Er ... perhaps *my assignment requires me to* ...? This is a standard class assignment requiring you to connect the requirements with a typical Bill Of Materials solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Many to Many relationship; call it `DishIngredients`.

Include `Amount` and `Units` fields in `DishIngredients`; this will let you specify the amount (e.g. 30) and units (e.g. grams) for each Dish/Ingredient combination.

Answer (score 0):

An Ingredient is a Product in a Recipe (or Dish) with it's Quantity (quantity should include Unit of Measure and be translatable between units). A Recipe contains many Ingredients. A Product can be in many Ingredients. And can be in Stock with a Quantity as well.